# A very strange crash. How do I fix it?

Tags: ios, crash

I have a very strange crash. I don't release the data variable.
My log is:

```
[NSConcreteData retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xa446a00
```

and code

```
- (void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
 if (!isThreadCreated)
 {
    self.isThreadCreated = YES;
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(createNewEncodingThread:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
 }
 [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
 [[AudiobookAppDelegate delegate].dateManager saveTimeLastActivities];

 if(trackFile && !isFotrbidGetNewData)
 {
    if (data) 
    {
        self.downloadedLengthOfFile+= data.length;
        [encodingArray addObject:data];
    }
 }     
}
```

[image]

Comment: where you are allocation memory to data?

Comment: I am guessing the same as @ssteinberg. You should actually retain it. Can you show us how do you init it?

Comment: @rishi, I don't create the data. It was created by ASI library. It is ASI delegates method.

Comment: @Voloda2 - then you need to retain the data, and then after you are done with that you need to release that.

Answer (score 0):

`encodingArray` got released somehow, so relevant code.

Comment: As you see, data was released. encodingArray was ok.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of code before adding object.

```
if(!encodingArray) {

 encodingArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

[encodingArray addObject:data];
```

Hope this will solve your problem.